# How do I create a dynamic dropdown menu in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Am experimenting with node Js. How do you create a dynamic dropdown menu?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="control-group">
   <%- form.label("state_or_province", false, {class: "control-label"}) %>
   <div class="controls">
   <!--       <%- form.input("state_or_province") %> -->
     <select id="Facility_state_or_province" name="Facility[state_or_province]" size="1">
       <% state_or_province_list.forEach(function (state_or_province_entry) { %>
         <option value = "<%= state_or_province_entry.lookup_code %>" <%= (facility.state_or_province != null) && (facility.state_or_province == state_or_province_entry.lookup_code) ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' %>><%= state_or_province_entry.meaning %></option>
   <% }); %>  
 </select>
    </div>
</div>
```